# Activity onResume( ) called when changing apps

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I would like to know if there's a way to differentiate when the onResume() method of an activity is called from the same app or a different application.

For example I would like to differentiate when my main activity's onResume() is called when I return to the app from Whatsapp or another activity of my app.

I know there's a way to do it with GET_TASKS permission but that method is deprecated and not recommended.

Thank you

Comment: "I would like to differentiate when my main activity's onResume() is called when I return to the app from Whatsapp or another activity of my app" -- why?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to know when app comes from the background to foreground in each `Activity`. This can be achieved using a class that extends the `Application` class and implements the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface. Firstly, here's the code for this class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    public boolean appInBackground;
    private Handler mHandler;  

    ...  

    @Override   
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());

        mHandler.cancelCallbacksAndMessages(null);  
        appInBackground = false;
    }   

    @Override   
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Paused", activity.getLocalClassName());

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override  
             public void run() {  
                  appInBackground = true;
             }  
        }, 5000);  
    }   

    ...  

}
```

If you notice in above code we are basically giving the app a grace period of 5 seconds to switch from one activity to other. If it exceeds more than that, it means the app was in background. The above class will need to registered in the `<application>` tag of your manifest file under `android:name:""` property as `android:name:"MyApplication"`.

To use this in your activity, override the `onPause()`:

```
private boolean resumedFromBg;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    resumedFromBg = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).appInBackground;
}
```

Let me know if you run into any issues~

Comment: Not really, actually I'm able to know when any of my activities comes from background to foreground. What I don't know is from which activity.

My Activity came to foreground after using Facebook messenger or after calling an intent from another activity of my own app?